# Как достать метод и метаданные из провайдера в NestJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Пишу обёртку `NestJS` обёртку для `Typegoose` так как существующая больше не поддерживается и там есть один критический недостаток, который я хочу устранить в своей реализации.

Задача: есть декоратор `@EventTrackerFor(schema: AnyClass)`, который принимает в себя класс `Typegoose`. Под капотом это работает так:

```typescript
export const EventTrackerFor = (schema: AnyClass) =>
    applyDecorators(Injectable, SetMetadata('tracker-for', schema.name));
```

А также декораторы `@Pre(eventName: PreEvents)` и `@Post(eventName: PostEvents)`, которые реализованы так:

```typescript
export const Post = (eventName: PreEvents) => SetMetadata('post', eventName);
export const Pre = (eventName: PostEvents) => SetMetadata('pre', eventName);
```

В итоге у пользователя библиотеки это будет выглядеть так:

```typescript
@EventTrackerFor(User)
class UserEventTracker {
    constructor(private readonly anyService: AnyService) {}

    @Pre(PreEvents.SAVE)
    @Post(PostEvents.SAVE)
    logOnAndAfterCreate() {
        console.log('user created')
    }
}

// ------------------------ Любой модуль
@Module({ 
    imports: [MyModule.forFeature([ {schema: User} ])],
    providers: [UserEventTracker]
})
class AnyModule {}
```

Необходимо как-то выцепить значение из декоратора `@EventTrackerFor()`, а также методы этого провайдера, которые помечены декораторами `@Pre()` и `@Post()`, включая значения, переданные в эти декораторы.

Пытался подглядеть реализацию этого поведения в различных пакетах, например таких, как `@nestjs/bull`, но там везде так много кода, что я так и не смог понять, как же они всё-таки это делают.

Репозиторий проекта: https://github.com/GrapeoffJS/kindagoose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить всех провайдеров в `NestJS` есть `DiscoveryModule`. Для получения метаданных из провайдеров необходим будет `Reflector` и `MetadataScanner`.

Пример как этим пользоваться ниже:

```typescript
import { DiscoveryService, MetadataScanner, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
class MetadataExplorer {
  constructor(
    private readonly discoveryService: DiscoveryService,  // экспортируется из DiscoveryModule
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
    private readonly metadataScanner: MetadataScanner,
  ) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    const allProviders = this.discoveryService.getProviders(); // Список всех провайдеров в приложении

    allProviders.forEach(({ instance }) => {
      const classMetadata = this.reflector.get('your_metadata_key', instance.constructor); // Вернёт все метаданные класса по ключу
    
      this.metadataScanner.scanFromPrototype( // Находит методы класса, которые имеют метаданные
        instance,
        Object.getPrototypeOf(instance),
        (methodName) => {
          const methodMetadata = this.reflector.get('your_metadata_key', instance[methodName]); // Вернёт все метаданные метода в классе по ключу
      },
    );
    });
  }
}
```

Ну и нужно не забыть добавить этот класс в провайдеры вашего модуля

Comment: Большое спасибо! Странно, что в документации неста нету ничего про DiscoveryModule. Я и до этого видел его в исходниках, но так и не смог понять, для чего же он был нужен. Укажу вас в пункте `special thanks` в документации к своему пакету :)